# Primeng table with row grouping and selection

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, primeng-table

How can I use row grouping and selection on checkbox in table row using primeng.
I have created one demo for it. while selecting one row, it is impacting other rows as well.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablerowgroup-demo-wix4gu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Do you still looking for solution for it ?

Comment: yes. I am still looking for the solution for it.

Comment: Any solution found @RishabhShah? I am on the same issue

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/11129
Primeng has raised a bug. they have not fixed it yet.